# Why is .onclick not working in this form even though Google Inspect shows no errors?

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm doing an assigment for my Javascript course (which most of my questions will be on) and I am using event handlers. So I use an .onclick so that when someone clicked on the form, something would display. But when I ran it in a browser, it does nothing. There are no typos in the HTML or Javascript, so I would appreciate help.

```js
function onclickform() {
  document.write("You found me!")
}

document.getElementById("formatReminder").onlick = onclickform;
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>5d</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="textField">
    <span id="formatReminder"></span>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: a `SPAN` will generally have no size ( unless you have assign rules in CSS ) so how can you be sure that you are clicking the span itself?

Comment: I thought the form would be the span, no?

Comment: `<span id="formatReminder"></span>` - no, you assign the listener to this element

Comment: Ok, I will try that.

Comment: Do you think setting the onclick to the FORM would work?

Comment: Just the form specifically?

Comment: Your onLICK is the issue it must be onclick.

Comment: What @epascarello is saying subtly that I will say more explicitly because people don't seem to be getting it is that you you have a typo. Try changing `onlick` to `onclick`.

Comment: I just realized that haha

Comment: if you assigned the `click` event listener to the FORM itself no matter which element you click would trigger the event ( caveats apply )... what is it that you are hoping to achieve?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I set it specifically to the FORM and when I click the text box the message displays and that is the only element in the form.

Comment: is that the desired result? Clearly you are also aware that `document.write` will effectively clear the document and insert ONLY the text you use when calling it

Comment: edit: another .innerHTML element worked, thank you all users, all my concerns have been addressed!

Answer (score 0):

There are some typos: `onlick` -> `onclick` and also you are targeting an element with dimensions 0x0. Put some content and it will work:

```js
function onclickform() {
  alert("You found me!")
}

document.getElementById("formatReminder").onclick = onclickform;
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>5d</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="textField">
    <span id="formatReminder">clickMe</span>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function onclickform() {
 document.write("You found me!")
}

document.getElementById("formatReminder").onlick = onclickform;
```

See on the last line of the code there is a typo. You typed onlick istead of onclick.

Comment: Adding `()` after `onclick` will call `onclick` (not to mention making it an rvalue which will cause a syntax error). OP is trying to assign the `onclick` handler, not call it. The browser will call it when the event occurs.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned a `SPAN` element occupies no physical space on the page unless it is assigned explicitly though CSS or inline style. Because of this you cannot find it when trying to `click` it. The following allows you to see the `span` and thus click it...

Using `document.write` will however overwrite the entire page which is perhaps not the desired outcome judging by the comment, in which case you want to update a DOM element and one method is to alter the DOM element's `innerHTML`

```js
function onclickform() {
    document.write("You found me!")
}

/* move along - no window licking here ;-) */
document.getElementById("formatReminder").onclick=onclickform;
```

```css
span{ width:1rem; height:1rem; background:red; display:block }
```

```html
<form>
    Write something here:
    <input type="text" id="textField"> 
    <span id="formatReminder"></span>
</form>
```

To update the `SPAN` element itself you need to manipulate either the `innerText` or `innerHTML` property of it.

```js
function onclickform(e) {
    this.innerHTML='You found me!';
}
document.getElementById("formatReminder2").onclick=onclickform;
```

```css
span{ min-width:1rem; width:1rem; height:1rem; background:red; display:inline-block; }
```

```html
<form>
    Write something here:
    <input type="text" id="textField"> 
    <span id="formatReminder2"></span>
</form>
```